# Creating your own SF Symbol - for unfound emoji?

Tags: swift

I've been looking all around SF Symbols - *I can find symbols for lungs - nose - bunny - all kinds of things* but no SF Icon for the emoji i want

Is there a way to create **my own SF Symbol** ?

---

*For my use case i'll need an SF Symbol -> can't use the existing emoji*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not exist as an SF Symbol.

You can create your own symbols: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/#creating-custom-symbols

…or just use the emoji.